# How to select record from two different tables

Tags: php, php-5.6

I have two tables which is

```
+----------------------------+
| task                       |
+----------------------------+
| id | t_title | t_assign_to |
+----------------------------+
```

---

```
+-----------------------------+
| task_employee               |
+-----------------------------+
| id | emp_name | emp_underon |
+-----------------------------+
```

---

My question is that i want to fetch t_assign_to FROM task table which having emp_underon = '2' in task_employee table with foreign key (t_assign_to)

```
<?php                
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM task");/// i got all value from here

  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM task_employee WHERE emp_underon ='2'");// i got all value from here

  //$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM task UNION SELECT * FROM task_employee WHERE emp_underon='2'");
  $count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
  {
    echo $row['t_assign_to'];
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the t_assign_to is the foreign key for task_employee
So i JOIN them together

Schema 1

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM task t INNER JOIN task_employee te ON t.t_assign_to = te.id";
```

Schema 2

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM task t,task_employee te WHERE t.t_assign_to = te.id";
```

If the field name in table is same with others field in others table, just alter the field name like:

```
$sql = "SELECT table.field as new_field_name FROM task t,task_employee te WHERE t.t_assign_to = te.id";
```

For you convenient,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM task t INNER JOIN task_employee te ON t.t_assign_to = te.id WHERE te.emp_underon = '2' "
$q = mysql_query($sql);
$c = mysql_num_rows($q);
if($c > 0)
{
  while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
  {
    echo $r['t_assign_to'];
  }
}
```

Comment: i didn't get any error but value also not getting,what is mean by te.id,id means what

Comment: I updated my answer, you may refer to it to make latest changes.
The te is shorthand of task_employee, it means i JOIN them together by their ID

Comment: count it will be return 0,but Db i have 2 row of emp_underon = '2'

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can get your answer by this query though I did not test this SQL.

```
select task.t_title, task.t_assign_to, task_employee.id as emp_id, task_employee.emp_name from task inner join task_employee on task.t_assign_to = task_employee.emp_underon where  task_employee.emp_underon = 2
```

Comment: Getting same error Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/srisanka/public_html/cupid/TV/managers.php on line 442

Comment: @yuvi would you please run that query to mysql ( By phpmyadmin )  and share with me that result?

Comment: i cann't access to phpmyadmin

Comment: @yuvi I have corrected my query as it had an typo error. Please try now.